# How to bold TextView with custom Font in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, textview, uitextview, uifont

I want to change my text in textview to BOLD and Italic on button click; but when I do this the custom font which is I am using for my textview also changed; but I want to use custom font.

Following is the code for bold textview

```swift
textView.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
```

I want to use custom font even when using bold or italic style

I have tried this but it does not work.

```swift
func attributedText() -> NSAttributedString {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font:(name: CustomFont, size: CGFloat(fontSize))]

    let boldFontAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0)]

    // 4
    return attributedString
}
```

And called as:

```swift
textView.attributedText = attributedText()
```

Comment: Show the code that sets the original custom font on the test view.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a regular font look bold, instead you need to have a bold font face for your custom font family (separate file) and add it together with regular font to your project's .plist [as shown here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app).

For example if your font is called a `CustomFont`, then you'd add the following files into your project

```
CustomFont
CustomFont-Bold
```

Now you get a bold font as

```
let boldFont = UIFont(name: "CustomFont-Bold", size: ...)
```